# Textbox restrict digit or puncuation

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have a textbox for user input. I want to handle the keydown event, preventing the user from entering anything other than letters. How can I do this?

Comment: Well, it's not an easy task as it could seem at the begining. You should also prohibit inserting the text with wrong characteres by pressing Ctrl+V/Shift+Ins. Consider PreviewTextInput event either.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `e.Key` and check if it's not a letter.

```
if ((e.Key < Key.A) && (e.Key > Key.Z))
    e.Handled = true;
```

if you set the `e.Handled` to `true`, the `char` won't appear.

Comment: That's allowing digits and other symbols as well. Are you really sure that doing this would work? Have a nice day :)

Comment: is it for WPF? I write in WPF.I want to write to keydown in WPF not Win

Comment: I just checked the code and it works. let me know if it helped you.